# What is Jekyll's organization?

Tags: mummy-2017

In *The Mummy* (2017),

> Dr. Jekyll said that he and several others are part of an organization whose purpose is to destroy evil.

What is the back story of this organization? How was it founded? Who was in it? What is its name?

Comment: I think (have not seen the film) he's referring to [The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen), which was also rumoured to become a part of the same Dark Universe _Mummy_ is in.

Comment: @Gallifreyan You have not missed much. It is a generic big budget action film with nothing special. I am just trying to understand an unclear aspect of it. I think that he used a different name for the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group is called Prodigium.

> "The Prodigium has been on the hunt for monsters  -- the purpose of which was not made known to us -- but it can be speculated that Jekyll and The Prodigium might be like Nick Fury's Avengers Initiative, a building block for this would-be shared universe of Universal Monsters." -[IGN](http://au.ign.com/articles/2016/12/05/the-mummy-filmmaker-alex-kurtzman-on-resurrecting-universals-classic-monsters-and-building-a-shared-universe)

And

> "Dark Universe films are connected by a mysterious multinational organization known as Prodigium. Led by the enigmatic and brilliant Dr. Henry Jekyll, Prodigium's mission is to track, study, and — when necessary — destroy evil embodied in the form of monsters in our world. Working outside the aegis of any government, and with practices concealed by millennia of secrecy, Prodigium protects the public from knowledge of the evil that exists just beyond the thin membrane of civilized society... and will go to any length to contain it."

That's a description from Universal but it is taken from this [Time](http://time.com/4790471/the-mummy-dark-universe-monster-franchise/) article.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for getting the name right and for finding evidence.